# What energy required when load added to a active spinning wheel

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, mass-energy

Visualize a 1mtr dia wheel with containers around its rim. Once the wheel (with empty containers) is at required RPM, energy required to maintain RPM is zero (if zero friction). But what energy is required to maintain the RPM whilst load was being added into the containers, whist it was spinning?

eg: Wheel (without additional loads) RPM=50, 1Kg loads are poured (in turn) into the perimeter containers. Each 1Kg load will go from zero speed to a linear velocity of 2.618 m/s very quickly.   How much energy required to maintain the RPM?

Numbers are for example, I wish to understand formula, not a result for the example :-)

Comment: So what ideas have you got in terms of solving your problem?

Comment: Only thought so far is to use calculation for getting just 1kg moving from zero to linear speed at stated r.  but not sure how to extrapolate that to n liters per x seconds